# Why does a button handle a click differently to non-buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, onclick

This may sound like a really silly question but I've noticed that the `Click` behaviour of my custom buttons differ when I inherit my class from a `Button` or `UserControl`.

I'm developing some controls with a customized look, among others, a button. The default user control class declaration is like this:

```
public partial class cButton : UserControl
```

After I added all of the GUI stuff, I added it to my form and tested the click-behaviour.

When I click the button in rapid succession, it only registers ever other click, not even every other click. I thought there is something wrong with the test code, but when I copied the exact code to a normal Winforms button, it registered every click no matter how fast.

Edit: the user control registers every click if I don't click to fast i.e. I wait a few seconds between every click.

I changed my custom control's decleration to inherit from the button class and made absolutely no other changes to any code:

```
public partial class cButton : Button
```

When I did my click-test the custom button behaved well, like a winforms button, not missing a click.

Just to test things, I added a list box to my form and added the same test code to its click event and it acted like a non-button, only registering a click every now and then.

I thought a click is supposed to be handled consistently, but apparently it's not that simple.

The question I have arising from this:

> What does a button do differently and what could I do to ensure proper
>   click-behaviour when it is not possible to inherit from a `Button`?

Comment: Two questions: is Click event for Button emitted when mouse button is pressed down or when it is released? Also: aren't some UserControl clicks misinterpreted as double clicks (and therefore skipped)?

Comment: @Kuba: I just tested, when press the mouse button and hold it for a few seconds, for both the button and the other controls the event fires only upon the mouse release.

Comment: OK, how about doubleclicks?

Comment: Okay, I first noticed that a button does not have a double-click, and other controls do. When I add some code to the double-click event, the click code fires upon the first mouse-release and the double-click code upon the second. My answer lies with @Charles may below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `UserControl` is differentiating between single clicks and double clicks.

To make it operate like a button, you need to set the `StandardDoubleClick` control style so that when the user clicks twice in rapid succession, the control registers two *single* clicks and raises two click events, and not a double click event.

Within the constructor add the following statement:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
```

Comment: Additionally, it might also be of interest to implement the `IButton` interface for controls which are to be used as buttons.  Aside from requiring implementation of the `PerformClick()` method, there are other useful things you might be interested in, such as working with a form's `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` properties.

Comment: Thanks. These are some really good suggestions and the actual answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're experiencing is that if you click the button too fast it registers as a double-click instead of a click. You can check this by writing to your output on double-click so that if your codes doesn't fire, check to see if double-click event did.